# When entering word, phrase related to it appears

Tags: javascript, bots

Imagine that I have an input to write words.. and I write "Stackoverflow" (then I click OK button) and a phrase appears down the input area like this one "Stackoverflow, is a place...".

It's nothing like this: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I want something like this:

```
<input type="text"/><input type="button" value="OK"/>
<div id="result"/>
```

Imagine that I write "Password" in the input, and in the result div appears something like "Need password changing? Follow this steps...". Or I write "Admin" and appears "The admin is Nickname".
It would be like a mini-bot support.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you refine your question slightly? Do you want a plugin that can do this, or do you want someone to write it for you, or are you having trouble with a specific part of your implementation?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I want something new, because I don't know where to start :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/28SBf/2/)):

```
var messages = {
    'stackoverflow': 'Stackoverflow, is a place...',
    'admin': 'The admin is Nickname',
    'password': 'Need password changing? Follow this steps...'
}

var result = document.getElementById('result');
var input = document.getElementById('input');

document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    var message = messages[input.value];
    if (message) {
       result.innerHTML = message;       
    } else {
       result.innerHTML = 'String not recognised';   
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="input" type="text"/>
<input id="submit" type="button" value="OK"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: AMAZING! Thanks, really! But some final questions... If I write "Admin" (capital letter), it gives me the "String not recognised", but the word is "admin", with lowercase. There is some way to make work with lowercase and uppercase at the same time?
And some improvements that you think this might need please :)
Thaaanks!

Comment: You can use the JavaScript toLowerCase() method :- http://jsfiddle.net/28SBf/3/ . Remember to accept the answer by clicking the tick if it's been useful.